# SOAP UI Property transfer from JDBC request into SOAP Request

Tags: jdbc, soapui

I have successfully created a JDBC request which is obtaining data from a db in the following XML:

```
<Results>
    <ResultSet fetchSize="64">
        <Row rowNumber="1">
            <POLICY>9999</POLICY>
            <CUSTOMER>00001</CUSTOMER>
        </Row>
    </ResultSet>
</Results>
```

I have a SOAP Request and I am trying to pass in both policy and customer values into specific locations on my request. I have set up a Property Transfer step to facilitate this.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/services" xmlns:v11="http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/types" xmlns:v12="http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/common">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:ReqMessage>
         <v11:ServiceHeader>
            <v11:CommonHeader>
               <v11:ServiceName>Treatment</v11:ServiceName>
               <v11:DateTimestamp>2017-02-10T10:51:00.000</v11:DateTimestamp>
            </v11:CommonHeader>
            <v11:ClientHeader>
               <v11:SourceSystem>System</v11:SourceSystem>
            </v11:ClientHeader>
            <v11:SecurityHeader>
              <v11:Username>9A</v11:Username> 
            </v11:SecurityHeader>     
         </v11:ServiceHeader>
         <v1:ServiceBody>
            <v12:TreatmentRequest>
               <v12:PolicyNumber></v12:PolicyNumber>
               <v12:MemberNumber></v12:MemberNumber>
            </v12:GetTreatmentTypesRequest>
         </v1:ServiceBody>
      </v1:GetProdAndTreatTypesReqMessage>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm struggling to know the Xpath for both source and target to insert into the Property Transfer step.

I am not using SOAP UI Pro.

Comment: I've sorted the Source Xpath now. I used //*:POLICY but still struggling with how I get it into the request fields

Comment: And ive now since sorted the Target by just using //*:PolicyNumber

Comment: Do you still need any help? Is it resolved?

Comment: Resolved thanks Rao. Easier than I thought!